# JavaScript: Replacing a string containing newlines

Tags: javascript, replace

Ref: [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/thd8oskn/2/)

I've a `<pre>` element containing multiple lines inside. Using JQuery, I'm calling `.html()` to get the `innerHTML`, and then doing a string `replace()` on the returned HTML string. However, the replace only works on the first line, and fails for the rest presumably because the returned `innerHTML` has newline.

Could you suggest a workaround for having both lines inside the `<pre>` replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the warning about using the `flags` parameter in the `replace` function, found at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace:

> Note: The flags argument is a non-standard Mozilla extension. A
>   string specifying a combination of regular expression flags. The use
>   of the flags parameter in the String.replace method is non-standard.
>   **Instead of using this parameter, use a RegExp object with the
>   corresponding flags**.

(emphasis is mine)

So, instead of using those parameters, you should use proper regexes instead:

```
string = string.replace(/&lt;your-login&gt;/g, userName);
string = string.replace(/&lt;repository-name&gt;/g, repoName);
```